# Hybrid Composer/FTP Drupal 8 workflow questions

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8

Is it ok to use composer on localhost to upgrade core and modules, and then FTP the files to the server?

I'm on shared hosting, and although it's possible to use SSH with GIT, it's a pain to set up...

Some information about my use case:

- No multiple users, no team, no multiple developers, I'm a one man show
- Small business sites
- I'm the only person adding content
- No need for version control, no module development, no coding

I'm a site builder, and the only code I touch are the CSS files of the theme. Will this workflow be ok?

1. Install Drupal 8 with composer
2. Import site into aquia dev desktop
3. Use composer to update modules and core
4. FTP sites folder to server
5. Use backup migrate when I alternate working from live to localhost and vice versa

Comment: "Is it okay" - yes, that's how you can do it. What have you tried so far to get this working? What are the remaining problems?

Comment: I haven't tried because I thought it was the "wrong" way to do things...!

Answer (score 1):

The question is very general and, I think, it has some "conflict" of ideas.

Your question:

> Is it ok to use composer on localhost to upgrade core and modules, and then FTP the files to the server

Technically yes. But this method has lots of disadvantages:

1. DR (Disaster Recovery) - What if you uploaded something that doesn't work? How quickly can you recover? With git its a matter of `git checkout`
2. Composer is environment-agnostic - When you run composer install, composer checks some dependencies in you machine and then decides what to install. What if you are missing some required packages in you remote machine? To fix this you should run composer install on the remote machine (via ssh)
3. FTP might take too long to finish - As apposed to `git` (or `rsync`) FTP will upload all files to the server. Other tools will upload just the diff between previous version and the current. So I will always choose `rsync` over FTP
4. Security - use SFTP

Your question:

> I'm a site builder, and the only code I touch are the CSS files of the theme. Will this workflow be ok

Sounds correct - but remember the composer issue..

Comment: Thanks for great answer! 2. In some cases I have no SSH, so that wouldn't work. Wouldn't the dependencies be installed on local machines, and then FTP these files to the server? 3. Can I use FreeFile Sync to the server? : https://freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=ftp-setup

Comment: Additionally, for situation 1. I rename and zip the folder in file manager, if it fails, I unzip and rename back to original name, takes 10 seconds ;)

Comment: About 2: Without ssh I think that you have no other option but to use some kind of file syncing program.  About freefile: I realy don't know.. never used it. About ziping as version controll: Well.. sound ok.. I think.. You should take into account the disk size. drupal + vendor directory might be super heavy

Comment: another comment about the dependencies: Without composer checking your dependencies on your remote machine - you can't be sure (or its very hard to be sure) that everything will work correctly